# ES6 property value shorthand of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to use property value shorthand but only when the value is defined, consider the following example:

```
const personByName = name => {
  const person = http(name)
  return { person, method: 'byName' }
}

personByName('john') // found person: { person: { name: 'john', age: 30 }, method: 'byName' }
personByName('paul') // not found: { method: 'byName' }
```

But the current output I get is:

```
personByName('paul') // not found: { person: undefined, method: 'byName' }
```

Comment: are you sure you dont want to `http.get(name)`?

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: @Naramsim `http` is a method, in this case was just added there as an example... I could call it `foo` or `bar` but this way looks something real :)

Comment: What's wrong with `person: undefined`? That's exactly what the `undefined` value is good for. Always using objects with the same properties is also more efficient.

Comment: @Bergi I think that's a different topic, I've specific question, and tried to simplify my problem with a specific and short example. I do agree with you in a general way, but in my specific case it does makes sense to omit the key if the value is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use *shorthand* property, `Object.assign` can be used:

```
const personByName = name => {
  const person = http(name);
  return Object.assign({ method: 'byName' }, person && { person });
}
```

Subsequent non-object `Object.assign` arguments are efficiently ignored, so falsy `person` doesn't affect the result.

This will work if `person` is expected to be an object, like is shown in original code.

In case only undefined values aren't allowed, it's:

```
Object.assign({ method: 'byName' }, person !== undefined && { person });
```

Comment: Clever! I could not think to add the condition there... Hands down

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
const personByName = name => {
  const person = http(name);
  const result = { method: 'byName' };
  if (person) { result.person = person; }
  return result;
}
```

There's no skipping declaring a property on an object if it's `undefined`.

Comment: Although it works I was trying to find a way to avoid that extra step conditional + mutation of the `result`... I guess you are right about that there is no way to skip a undefined property.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote :/ it would be nice if the down-voter could add a comment

Answer (score 1):

In ES2018, you may use the ternary operator to eval if `a` defined and object spread to build an object which contains `a` and `b`, or just `b`:

```js
const a = 1
const b = { b: 2 }
const c = a ? { a, ...b } : b

console.log( c )
```

```js
const a = undefined
const b = { b: 2 }
const c = a ? { a, ...b } : b

console.log( c )
```

Comment: It should be noted that it's ES2018, not ES6.

Comment: @estus fixed ;-)

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @FelixKling BTW, how would you refer to `...`? *object property spreading*?

Comment: I think the proposal uses the terms, “object spread” and “object rest”. But “spread/rest properties” would also be good.

Comment: @FelixKling Done!

Answer (score 0):

In ES2018 this can be done even without "type checks"

```js
let a = { a: 1 }
let b = { b: 2 }
let c = undefined
let d = { d: 4 }

let x = {...a, ...b, ...c, ...d};      // {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
//                      ┗━━ undefined
console.log(x)
```

This works for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) vars. Some attention to "non empty strings":

```js
let a = { a: 1 }
let b = { b: 2 }
let c = undefined // ━┓
let c1 = false    //  ╏
let c2 = 0        //  ╏
let c3 = -0       //  ┣╍ falsy
let c4 = 0n       //  ╏
let c5 = ''       //  ╏
let c6 = null     //  ╏
let c7 = NaN      // ━┛
let d = { d: 4 }

let x = {...a, ...b, ...c, ...c1, ...c2, ...c3, ...c4, ...c5, ...c6, ...c7, ...d}; 
//                      ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ falsy ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
console.log(x)   // OK: {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}

let t1 = true   
let t2 = 789
let y = {...a, ...b, ...t1, ...t2, ...d}; 
console.log(y)   // OK: {a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}

// Non empty string!
let t3 = 'abc'
let z = {...a, ...b, ...t3, ...d}; 
console.log(z)   // {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", a: 1, b: 2, d: 4}
//                   ┗━━━━━━━ !!! ━━━━━━━┛
```